# NGX countdown timer not counting down accurately for 'leftTime' parameter is greater than 24 hrs

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, countdown

For the below `leftTime` configuration, if i pass value greater than `864000`, timer value is not starting from a value greater than 24 hrs.

```
<countdown [config]="{leftTime: `864000`}"></countdown>
```

Ex:

```
1. If leftTime: `864000`, Timer counts down from `24:00:00`
2. If leftTime: `900000`, Timer counts down from `10:00:00`
```

What should i do obtain accurate timer start hrs if i pass seconds value greater than `864000` to `leftTime` parameter?

Comment: try 86399 as a value.

Comment: try my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below statement :-

```
<countdown [config]="{ leftTime: 864000, format: 'd:HH:m:s' }"></countdown>
```

Comment: The question is how to use a `leftTime` value greater than 864000. This shows a `leftTime` value equal to 864000. If the OP uses their example of 900000, will this work? That's the question that needs answering.

Comment: @AakashGarg I tried the above code snip with providind data like below: ```<countdown [config]="{ leftTime: 900000, format: 'd:HH:m:s' }"></countdown>``` However, i get a timer starting like this: `11:10:00:00`. What am i missing?

Comment: @AakashGarg StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-countdown-setup-mfbxtp

Comment: Nevermind. I think i got confused with the numbers. Your solution is good! ```1) 86400 seconds implies 24 hours. Count down start as 1:00:00:00```  ```2) 90000 seconds implies 25 hours. Count down start as 2:01:00:00``` All all good now. Thank you very much. +1 for your solution.

Comment: @AakashGarg I had a question after testing this. After the countdown timer goes down to zero, the timer stops and its state sticks as `1:00:00:00`. Isn't that misleading? It should come down as `00:00:00:00` right? I meant this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-countdown-setup-mfbxtp

Comment: need to check doc for that.

Comment: refer https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe for what formats you can pass above.

Comment: @AakashGarg, I tried to inspect the docs, but i could't find a suitable format for dispaying days as `00:00:00:00`. I have the same issue --> when the timer sticks, it dispaying as `01:00:00:00`